# adding multiple lines of text to detailTextLabel without making a custom cell

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to add multiple lines of text as a detailTextLabel without making a custom cell in my application? If so can anyone show me the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line of code
`cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = x;`
will set the number of lines your cell will display (x being the number of lines you need to display).  Set to 0 if you want to remove the maximum limit and display as many lines as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Change style of your cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```